# Zlib is breaking CodeIgniter Zip Downloader and PHPExcel

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, phpexcel, zlib

I'm facing an issue where if Zlib compression is enabled on the web server, downloading any zip file using CodeIgniter's `force_download` function in the system's `download_helper.php` file breaks the archive file and prevents users from opening it.

[image]

Here is the `force_download` function for zipped files after compressing `XLSX` files in it:

```
    function force_download($filename = '', $data = '')
    {
        if ($filename == '' OR $data == '')
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Try to determine if the filename includes a file extension.
        // We need it in order to set the MIME type
        if (FALSE === strpos($filename, '.'))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Grab the file extension
        $x = explode('.', $filename);
        $extension = end($x);

        // Load the mime types
        if (defined('ENVIRONMENT') AND is_file(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/mimes.php'))
        {
            include(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/mimes.php');
        }
        elseif (is_file(APPPATH.'config/mimes.php'))
        {
            include(APPPATH.'config/mimes.php');
        }

        // Set a default mime if we can't find it
        if ( ! isset($mimes[$extension]))
        {
            $mime = 'application/octet-stream';
        }
        else
        {
            $mime = (is_array($mimes[$extension])) ? $mimes[$extension][0] : $mimes[$extension];
        }

        // Generate the server headers
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE") !== FALSE)
        {
            header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header('Pragma: public');
            header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
        }
        else
        {
            header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
        }

        exit($data);
    }
```

Enabling Zlib also breaks PHPExcel by producing garbled characters in Excel files as you can see in this image.

[image]

PHPExcel download function for a single `XLSX` file. Here's the gist for the entire Excel generator, zip, and downloader functions https://gist.github.com/TheWebAuthor/5773e56086df4317c7cf54aab45df328

```
ob_end_clean();                    
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');                            
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');                            
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .$fileinfo['filename'] . '_' . $customerId . '_' . date("mdy") . '.xls');              
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');                            
header('Expires: 0');                            
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');                            
header('Pragma: public');                            
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));                            
ob_clean();                            
flush();                            
readfile($file);
```

Is there a proper workaround to enable Zlib and not breaking these features?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the force_download function takes care of sending headers for you.

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't use `pragma:public` as that says any cache should feel free to cache the document. You may be looking at a cached (and corrupted) document rather than the latest version of the file.

Comment: @S.Imp Changed `pragma:public` to `pragma:no-cache` and it still gives an error when opening the archive.

Comment: Please see answer below and clarify if I misunderstand.

Comment: What version of Codeigniter is that? The [latest force_download](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/download_helper.php#L64) accepts a third parameter. If your version of Codeigniter is old, it may also lack the correct mime type for whatever file you are downloading. Unfortunately, the code you have posted tells us *nothing at all* about what kind of file you are actually sending to the user.

Comment: @S.Imp It is 2.1.2

Comment: Well that's pretty darn old. It looks like even the [latest Zip library download function](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Zip.php#L459) fails to ask for a mime type to be specified. This is a longshot, but maybe try sending a mime type header before your `$this->zip->download` call. Does it work when there's only one excel file?

Comment: Also wondering what happens if you save the zip file and then try to open the saved file. Does your browser prompt you to name it xyz.zip.**gz** or something? Or does it prompt you to save it with the intended filename? Also, have you tried examining the response headers from your server to see what the actual mime type is?

Comment: I also noticed that you fail to initialize `$download_data` as an array before adding elements to it. I've added some additional detail to my answer below. hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't clearly indicated all the details of your script, but you start off describing a "zip file" and referring to "archives." However, what little code you have posted sends a content-type header for an excel file. If you send a zip file to the browser but tell the browser its mime type is **application/vnd.ms-excel** then this could be your problem.

Have you considered just using the force_download function? This controller works for me whether the file is excel or zip:

```
public function download() {
    $filepath = "/path/to/file.zip";
     // or you can send an Excel file
    $filepath = "/path/to/file.xls";

    $filename = basename($filepath);

    $data = file_get_contents($filepath);

    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download($filename, $data);
}
```

The [force_download function has built-in code to sniff out the correct mime type based on the file extension](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/download_helper.php#L64). Depending on your version of Codeigniter, you may need to specify a third parameter of **TRUE**.

I have replicated the "garbled character" problem you describe by setting a mime type of **application/vnd.ms-excel** but sending a ZIP file. Conversely, I have successfully downloaded both ZIP and XLS files by just using the force_download function.

**EDIT**
Having seen some code, I'd like to suggest that you rework your logic around [line 229](/blob/develop/system/libraries/Zip.php#L229) as it is a little bit awkward to be checking `count($result)` inside your foreach loop. You might check that before entering a foreach loop.

More importantly, you fail to initialize `$download_data` as an array before assigning array elements. Depending on what your environment and error_reporting settings are, this may trigger an E_NOTICE or E_WARNING that causes additional output before you start to output the contents of your zip file. If your code ends up outputting unwanted characters before it starts outputting the actual binary data of your zip archive, this will corrupt the file. Another possibility is that a reference to the undefined variable will cause an E_NOTICE error to be emitted to stdout, which can cause any subsequent header commands to fail because you cannot send header commands once you have begun outputting text.

Another possibility is an incorrect mime type. Your version of Codeigniter is quite old, but I think it's unlikely that this is a problem. If you can, try inspecting the response headers sent to your browser to see if they are **application/x-gzip** or **application/zip** or something else.

Finally, you should check the **compress_output** setting in [appilcation/config.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L420). Please note the comments there:

```php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Output Compression
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Enables Gzip output compression for faster page loads.  When enabled,
| the output class will test whether your server supports Gzip.
| Even if it does, however, not all browsers support compression
| so enable only if you are reasonably sure your visitors can handle it.
|
| Only used if zlib.output_compression is turned off in your php.ini.
| Please do not use it together with httpd-level output compression.
|
| VERY IMPORTANT:  If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it
| means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could
| even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts.  For
| compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called
| by the output class.  Do not 'echo' any values with compression enabled.
|
*/
```

Comment: @Daniel-harris Any luck fixing this problem?

Comment: The function is already being used as described in the question.

Comment: @DanielHarris nowhere in your question do you invoke the force_download function. Also, the "Headers for PHPExcel download function" code you posted sends a mime type for an excel file. If you are outputting a zip file but sending headers for an XLS file, you'll get the garbled character issue you describe. If you are, in fact, using the force_download function, consider supplying a third parameter of TRUE to force CodeIgniter to read a mime type from your filename's extension.

Comment: The question is implying to two different issues (PHPExcel and CodeIgniter zip downloader) caused by the same problem (Zlib). I mentioned that the `force_download` function is being used in the first paragraph.

Comment: @DanielHarris I have zlib enabled. It works just fine. I don't think zlib is your problem. I think it's incorrect mime types. However, you haven't actually posted all your code so it's impossible to say now, isn't it?

Comment: Zlib is in fact the problem. When Zlib is enabled, the downloaders do not work properly. When it's disabled, no problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your code and we could **see** if it's the problem. Zlib is enabled on my workstation and the built-in force_download function works just fine for both zip files and xls files if you use it properly. Your question shows two completely different sets of header commands, doesn't clearly indicate which you are actually using, and fails completely to show whether your code is sending a zip file or xls file.

Comment: I added the code for the `force_download` function, which can already be found in CodeIgniter's `system/helpers/download_helper.php` file. The PHPExcel downloader function is already posted and doesn't need to be further explained.

Comment: @DanielHarris If you had actually read my answer, you'd see that I'm fully aware of the source code of the force_download function because I provided a link to the original source on github. What you have not provided is *any* information about how you *generate* your file, whether this file is zip archive or whether it's an XLS file, and how exactly your code *calls the force_download function.* Do you set the third parameter ($set_mime) to **TRUE**?

Comment: Gist https://gist.github.com/TheWebAuthor/5773e56086df4317c7cf54aab45df328

Comment: @DanielHarris based on the code gist you posted, I've added some other stuff to check to my answer above. Firstly, you need to define $download_data as an array before trying to append elements to it. you might also need to check your config file against the built-in zlib that may or may not be installed with your web server.